# python gnupg verify file

Tags: python, gnupg

I am not sure why this is not working (Python 2.7.5) - the files created in the temp directory I *can* validate, but python will not. Help?

I'm not sure if I am using the gpg.verify_file function wrong, or if I am not understanding the right way to tell python I trust the key that is being imported, or what. When I open my shell and enter the temp directory, I have no problem verifying the file against the sig, so I know it should validate.

Unfortunately 99% of the Python GnuPG examples out there are encryption, which this is not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2
import gnupg
import tempfile
import shutil
from pprint import pprint

def getStartTlsPolicy():
    policyURL = 'https://dl.eff.org/starttls-everywhere/policy.json'
    policyASC = 'https://dl.eff.org/starttls-everywhere/policy.json.asc'
    publicKEY = 'https://dl.eff.org/starttls-everywhere/public-key.txt'
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(policyURL, timeout=5)
    except:
        return '{}'
    try:
        signature = urllib2.urlopen(policyASC, timeout=5)
    except:
        return '{}'
    try:
        keyblock = urllib2.urlopen(publicKEY, timeout=5)
    except:
        return '{}'
    jsondata = response.read()
    sigdata = signature.read()
    keyfile = keyblock.read()
    # GnuPG stuff here
    dirpath = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=dirpath)
    gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
    sigfile = open(dirpath + '/policy.json.asc', 'w+')
    sigfile.write(sigdata)
    jsonfile = open(dirpath + '/policy.json', 'w+')
    jsonfile.write(jsondata)
    jsonfile.close()
    fingerlist = []
    fingerlist.append('B693F33372E965D76D55368616EEA65D03326C9D')
    gpg.import_keys(keyfile)
    gpg.trust_keys(fingerlist, 'TRUST_FULLY')
    verified = gpg.verify_file(sigfile, dirpath + '/policy.json', 'key_id=842AEA40C5BCD6E1')
    if not verified:
        print "signature verify failed"
        public_keys = gpg.list_keys()
        pprint(public_keys)
        sigfile.close()
        #shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
        print dirpath
        return '{}'
    sigfile.close()
    shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
    return jsondata

jsondata = getStartTlsPolicy()
print jsondata
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out. Writing the signature to file is not enough, you have to close and then reopen it in read only mode. Why I do not know, but that works.